# TCPDF position barcode on correct page

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

How do I set page of barcode. I want it to be on top of first one, but it seems random and I cant find answer in documentation!!
My code

```
$pdfBrc = new FPDI(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$fileBrc = realpath($output);

$pagecountBrc = $pdfBrc->setSourceFile($fileBrc);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $pagecountBrc; $i++) {
    $tplBrc = $pdfBrc->importPage($i);
    $sizeBrc = $pdfBrc->getTemplateSize($tplBrc);
    $orientationBrc = $sizeBrc['h'] > $sizeBrc['w'] ? 'P' : 'L';
    $pdfBrc->AddPage($orientationBrc);
    $pdfBrc->useTemplate($tplBrc, null, null, $sizeBrc['w'], $sizeBrc['h'], true);
}

$styleBrc = array(
            'position' => 1,
            'align' => 'C',
            'stretch' => false,
            'fitwidth' => true,
            'cellfitalign' => '',
            'border' => false,
            'hpadding' => 'auto',
            'vpadding' => 'auto',
            'fgcolor' => array(0, 0, 0),
            'bgcolor' => false, //array(255,255,255),
            'text' => true,
            'font' => 'helvetica',
            'fontsize' => 8,
            'stretchtext' => 4
);

$pdfBrc->write1DBarcode('KPV09008008986', 'C128B', 40, 2, 50, 15, 0.8, $styleBrc, 'N');

$pdfBrc->Ln();
```

Comment: The logic in your script put the barcode on the last page... if you want to place it on a specific page you should simply move the barcode into the for-loop and wrap it in an if-statement for page 1.

Comment: @Setasign thnx m8 it works. Though there is an easier option